# Remove item from localStorage after onClick and don't show again anymore after browser refresh in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

In my React app I am showing a banner yes or no, based on React state and some values set in `localStorage`.

1. After close button is clicked, it's state `showBanner` is saved to localStorage and doesn't show the banner anymore
2. After *2* times using a page url in the React app with query param `redirect=my-site` it doesn't show the banner anymore:

   ```
   import queryString from 'query-string';

   const location = useLocation();
   const queryParams = queryString.parse(location.search);

   const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);

   const handleClick = () => {
    setShowBanner(false);
    localStorage.removeItem('redirect');
   };

   const hasQp = queryString
    .stringify(queryParams)
    .includes('redirect=my-site');

   const initialCount = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && hasQp) {
      return Number(localStorage.getItem('redirect')) || 0;
    }
    return null;
   };

   const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);

   const show = showBanner && hasQp && count! < 3;

   useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('my-banner');

    if (data !== null) {
      setShowBanner(JSON.parse(data));
    }
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('my-banner', JSON.stringify(showBanner));
   }, [showBanner]);

   useEffect(() => {
    let pageView = count;

    if (pageView === 0) {
      pageView = 1;
    } else {
      pageView = Number(pageView) + 1;
    }

    if (hasQp && showBanner === true) {
      localStorage.setItem('redirect', String(pageView));
      setCount(pageView);
    }
   }, []);
   ```

This is working fine (when you see some good code improvements let me know :) ).

But as soon the user clicks the close button I don't want the `localStorage` item `redirect` no longer appears. Now after refreshing the page it appears again.

How do i get this to work?

Comment: When you refresh the page and the `useEffect` functions run, is `if (hasQp && showBanner === true) {` evaluating to `true`?  If so, that would be why the `'redirect'` item is being written to `localStorage`.

Comment: @David yeah exactly, so I am curious why inside if block `if (hasQp && showBanner === true) {}` when I log `showBanner` `console.log(showBanner)` this returns always true? When I click the close I was expecting it should changes to false?

Comment: Because you *explicitly define it* as `true`?  `const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);`  If you're expecting state updates to persist across a page refresh then your expectation is simply wrong.  (And begs the question of why you were using `localStorage` in the first place if you were expecting state to persist...)

Comment: @David ok that makes scenes. React state isn't persistent indeed. So how can I solve this in my example? I need to know somehow if the value of the localStorage item `my-banner` is true or false? How do I fetch that in the if-block where I added `showBanner === true`?

Comment: I would suggest that you don't duplicate the "show banner" data.  It's already in `localStorage` and can be read from that at any time.  There's no reason to also copy it to state.  That seems to be the root of the issue.

Comment: @David Sorry what do you mean exactly, where do I duplicate it for example? I do need this state right const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);? Or do I have to replace `true` inside this hook with the `localStorage` item?

Answer (score 0):

If this is executing when the page loads:

```
localStorage.setItem('redirect', String(pageView));
```

Then that means this is `true`:

```
if (hasQp && showBanner === true)
```

The `hasQp` value is `true`, which means this is `true`:

```
const hasQp = queryString
 .stringify(queryParams)
 .includes('redirect=my-site');
```

And `showBanner` is `true` because it's always initialized to `true`:

```
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);
```

It's not 100% clear to me why you need this state value, but you could try initializing it to `false` by default:

```
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);
```

But more to the point, I don't think you need this state value at all.  It's basically a duplicate of data that's in `localStorage`.  But since both state and `localStorage` are always available to you, I don't see a reason to duplicate data between them.

Remove that state value entirely and just use `localStorage`.  An example of checking the value directly might be:

```
if (hasQp && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my-banner')))
```

Which of course could be refactored to reduce code.  For example, consider a helper function to get the value:

```
const showBanner = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem('my-banner') ?? false;
  if (data) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
};
```

Then the check could be:

```
if (hasQp && showBanner())
```

There are likely a variety of ways to refactor the code, but overall the point is to not duplicate data.  In thie case a value is being stored in `localStorage` *instead of* React state because it needs to persist across page loads.  Just keep that value in `localStorage` and use it from there.

Comment: Thanks! When I remove the state `const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);` 1) how do I add for example `hasQp && count! < 3` to the helper function `showBanner()` and 2) in the `onClick` I have to replace the state now and set localStorage item `my-banner` to false. How do I do that?

Comment: @meez: I'm not sure where the struggle is... Are you just asking how to read and write the value in `localStorage`?  Your code already does that.  My suggestion is simply to *only* do that and not duplicate the value to state.