# Show and hide element with only localStorage in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, show-hide

I need to get rid of my React state when hiding my banner. I want to show/hide it with *only* `localStorage`.

I have an onClick handler:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    const data = false;
    localStorage.setItem('show-banner', data);
  };
```

which I pass to the close button inside my banner component:

```
<MyBanner onClick={handleClick} />
```

How do I show the banner by default and hide it when handleClick function gets executed (without React state but managed by localStorage `setItem` and `getItem`?

Comment: However you have to listen to the change in storage in useEffect may be ....

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the state of local storage in `handleClick` and toggle with a negation `!`

Code looks like this:

```js
  const handleClick = () => {
    const data = !(localStorage.getItem('show-banner') === 'true' || false); // change default false or true value depending on the initial status of the banner
    localStorage.setItem('show-banner', data);
  };
```

Explanation:
Code will try to get value from local storage, the first time it will be undefined falling back to the default value after `||`.

Then 2nd, and subsequent times, it will read the value from local storage. However **local storage will read the value as a String**, hence the comparison to `'true'` is required.

If your local storage value is JSON object or array, a JSON.parse would be required when reading.

Comment: Ok and how do I use this to conditionally show/hide the banner like `{showBanner && <MyBanner onClick={handleClick} />}`?

Comment: @meez to toggle use state that is the whole point of React Js to write declarative code

Comment: Above `handleClick ` I added a useEffect: `useEffect(() => {
    const data = true;
    localStorage.setItem('show-banner', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, []);` and then inside handleClick: `const data = false;
    localStorage.setItem('show-banner', JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @RajendranNadar so your advice is always use React state to toggle. Because I was in a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207916/remove-item-from-localstorage-after-onclick-and-dont-show-again-anymore-after-b) where somebody suggest to remove the React state. Is he wrong then? What's your opinion?

Comment: @meez both ways may work with pros and cons. the referenced page in exchange of using the `state`  now localstorage is read (and re-read) in multiple places which some may argue is dirtier, but some may like the lack of duplication. My personal opinion, having the state makes more sense since useEffect can track the change in an optimized way and you reduce the interactions to an "external dependency" in the name of the local storage from your code. (imagine tomorrow you want to use a different storage, your changes will be fewer)